# export MongoDB Object id to YAML file

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I am trying to store a MongoDb Object id into a yaml file, I will also need to load this back. But I am currently struggling on exporting this into a yaml file. I found an example that suggest this can be done. The example I am trying to follow is here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/f0wDJAnCOS0

```
# My variable name
collection_insert_id
ObjectId('5923bb676cab3d37c45012a1')

# variable type
type(collection_insert_id)
<class 'bson.objectid.ObjectId'>

# this is a snip of the example I am following, Its throwing an error
def objectid_representer(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_scalar("!bson.objectid.ObjectId", str(data))

yaml.SafeDumper.add_representer(collection_insert_id, objectid_representer)
yaml.safe_dump(my_dict, 'data.yaml',default_flow_style=False)


# This is the error I get when passing the second line.
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/ws/mastarke-sjc/pyats2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", 
line 216, in safe_dump
return dump_all([data], stream, Dumper=SafeDumper, **kwds)
  File "/ws/mastarke-sjc/pyats2/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 188, in dump_all
dumper.represent(data)
File "/ws/mastarke-sjc/pyats2/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/yaml/representer.py", line 26, in represent
node = self.represent_data(data)
File "/ws/mastarke-sjc/pyats2/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/yaml/representer.py", line 47, in represent_data
node = self.yaml_representers[data_types[0]](self, data)
File "/ws/mastarke-sjc/pyats2/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/yaml/representer.py", line 203, in represent_dict
return self.represent_mapping('tag:yaml.org,2002:map', data)
File "/ws/mastarke-sjc/pyats2/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/yaml/representer.py", line 116, in represent_mapping
node_value = self.represent_data(item_value)
File "/ws/mastarke-sjc/pyats2/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/yaml/representer.py", line 57, in represent_data
node = self.yaml_representers[None](self, data)
File "/ws/mastarke-sjc/pyats2/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/yaml/representer.py", line 227, in represent_undefined
raise RepresenterError("cannot represent an object: %s" % data)
yaml.representer.RepresenterError: cannot represent an object: 
5923bb676cab3d37c45012a1


# This is the code I am trying to follow that suggest how to send MongoDB 
# object id to yaml file
def objectid_representer(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_scalar("!bson.objectid.ObjectId", str(data))

yaml.SafeDumper.add_representer(objectid.ObjectId, objectid_representer)
yaml.safe_dump(doc_with_objectid, yamlfile, default_flow_style=False)
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/ to json, then one of `yaml.dump(json.load())`. Read disclaimer in the docs.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but the document your referencing seems to be more on exporting when working directly in MongoDB shell. I am interfacing with Mongo via Python 3, so I'm looking for solution using Python.

Comment: No, you are not. I am not answering the question, but suggesting to use available tools. If you really need to do it manually, have you tried to `yaml.dump` it directly?